# mikrotik command works manually but not in script

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

I wrote some script and run it through .rsc file but have an error.

[admin@MikroTik] > /ip firewall filter disable numbers=16
Results in

no items defined
If I manually key in the command then its working.

Does anyone have an idea why this going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It does work with some random mikrotik of mine (v6.35.4).
Did you try also this?

```
/ip firewall filter disable 16
```

Anyway I think it's more secure to filter your rule by "real" filters, not its number which may vary if some rule is added before. Maybe you can try something like

```
/ip firewall filter disable  [ find src-address="192.168.11.0/24" and dst-address="192.168.68.0/24" ]
```

and adapt your filters to your needs